# What is the "projective limit" of a polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Bayer and Mumford, *What can be computed in algebraic geometry*, reads (in part):

> Let $S = k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$ be the homogeneous coordinate ring of $\mathbb{P}^n$.
>
> [. . .]
>
> Choose a one-parameter subgroup $\lambda(t) < GL_{n+1}$ of the form
>   $$\lambda(t) = \begin{bmatrix}t^{w_0} \\ & t^{w_1} \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & t^{w_n} \end{bmatrix}$$
>   where $W = (w_0, \ldots, w_n)$ is a vector of integer weights.
>
> [. . .]
>
> Let $\lambda$ act on $S$ by mapping each $x_i$ to $t^{w_i} x_i$.
>
> [. . .]
>
> We take the projective limit $in(f) = \lim_{t \to 0} \lambda f$ by collecting the terms of $\lambda f$ involving the least power of $t$.

I'm not clear on this last sentence.  Are they *defining* the term "projective limit" and the notation $\lim_{t \to 0}$ here?  Or is there a general notion of a projective limit of -- polynomials?  ring elements? -- that is being used here?

Comment: They are defining it (and not sure why they use the  word `projective').

Comment: Well, if you view things geometrically, it's the flat limit of some subschemes of projective space, so if they're defining it that could be the reason.